# cant find nas mediaplayer on vista

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, networking, nas, media-player

I have a Icy Box IB MP3010HW media player.  I have it on wireless and have it connected to my TP Link WR641G router and can access the radio on the net.

The problem i have is Vista SP2 does not see it.  I don't know how to go about making it find it. I ran the ping test (I think it is) by going through Firefox (IP address is 192.168.1.101) and it came up with a simple HTML+cgi example which I'm assuming means it working.

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way you connect the device here are a few excepts:

**Wired**

> Select to set the Network Setting. Before use the Network functions, please check
>   following items:
>   1) Connect the Player to Network first;
>
> 2) Please enable NetBIOS of TCP/IP on computer;
>
> 3) Please turn off your PC's firewall;
>
> 4) Please enable your PC's "Guest" account;
>
> 5) Please share the folders which you wish to browse on your PC,
>
> and make sure that "Everyone" or "Guest" has the right to access.

Also from what I read in the manual it looks like you are supposed to browse from your mediaplayer to your pc.

> 7.5.1 Browsing through Workgroup
>   You can choose the workgroup which your PC belongs to from the workgroup list, find your PC name,
>   and press to confirm.
>
> Note:
>   1. While browsing high definition video files (resolution up to 720p / 1080i) via
>   Ethernet or WLAN, the video might be buffering. It is normal due to the limit of network
>   speed or signal strength.
>   2. Due to different network conditions, sometimes the workgroup might not be accessed or
>   shown in the list. And then you need to use "My_Shortcuts" to browse shared files.

I found the manual [here](http://www.raidsonic.de/de/data/driver/ICY_BOX/handbuch/IB_MP3010HW_manual_en_ru_it_cz_fr.zip)

Comment: yes i read the manual from my understanding it talks about the nas function it says enter the ip addy of the player in to the run box of vista then the book says then u can view,and edit the stored files on the hard disk on the player in this way, you can also playback and copy files via network between pc and the player